# Can I find out where a webpage visitor came from?

Tags: analytics, web-analytics

When someone visits my site, is there any info at all I can access that will tell me where they came from that I can store in a database? I'm not trying to find out their history or track them or anything, I just want to know how users are finding my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Analytics there's a Referral Traffic page that shows you the top sources that your visitors originate from. Google Analytics is easy to set up on your site, in case your don't have it.

[image]

Comment: The reason I asked is I want to generate some custom reports, does google have an API that will let me access this information?

Comment: Haven't used itm but they do. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js